# Theta runtime of recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, runtime, big-o

How do I calculate the Theta runtime of this given code:

```
void f(int n)
{
    for (int i=3; i<n; ++i)
        for (int j=0; j<i; ++j)
            f(n-1);
}
```

So far i got this, but I don't know if it's right or how to bring it in Theta notation.

```
f(n) = n^2 * f(n-1)
f(n) = n^2 * (n-1)^2 * f(n-2)
f(n) = n^2 * (n-1)^2 * (n-2)^2 * f(n-3) 
...
```

Comment: Hint:  n^2 * (n-1)^2 * (n-2)^2 * ... = (n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...)^2

Comment: `f` does not have a return value, so `f(n)` does not _equal_ to anything; the big-Theta (also big-O) notation is concerned about the number of operations performed while executing the algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each nested for-loop is O(N^2) complexity, and each time you call a function inside another function, the complexity is multiplied, you end up with O((N!)^2), where `N` is also the number of times you recurse.  This is of course because `N! = N*(N-1)*(N-2)*...*(N-N+1)`, and all the values used to create the factorial are squared.

Answer (score 1):

If we replace that 3 with a zero (which obviously doesn't change anything about the Θ) we can very easily derive the exact amount of function calls:

> Θ<sub>*f* ( *1* )</sub> = 1
>   Θ<sub>*f* ( *n* )</sub> = *n*<sup>2</sup> ⋅ Θ<sub>*f* ( *n*-1 )</sub>         ∀ *n* > 0

So, using commutativeness of the product,

> <sub>*n*</sub>                 <sub>*n*</sub>          <sub>*n*</sub>
>   Θ<sub>*f* ( *n* )</sub> =   ∏   *j* <sup>2</sup>   =   ∏ *j*   ⋅  ∏ *j*  =  *n*! ⋅ *n*!
>                  *i* =1             *i* =1     *i* =1
>  = (*n*!)<sup>2</sup>

As Jason said.

Comment: Do the spaces work out correctly? It's rather hackish, I hate not to have LaTeX / MathJax at hand.